# Python variables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I would like to use Python variables as table name, column name and value but this query don't working:

```
def dodaj_do_bazy (wartosc, miejsce, tabela):

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","slawomir","12345","testpy" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
#sql = "INSERT INTO ",tabela,"(",miejsce,") VALUES(",wartosc,")"
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute('INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)' % tabela, miejsce, (wartosc))
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
db.close()


dodaj_do_bazy(wpis_email, "email", "mail")
```

Answer (score 0):

from my tests...

MySQLdb expects tuples as variables, so enclose in parenthesis

`cursor.execute('INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)' % (tabela, miejsce, wartosc))`

Does this help?

Comment: So, prepare the statement and print it
How does it look?

Any percentage character sign (%) in `wpis_email`? Because these have to be escaped (%%)

Comment: If I print this: print wpis_email this returns me clean variable

Answer (score 0):

found it here on SO:

This is working for me now (python  2.7.6, MariaDB)

`sql =  """INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)""" %  ( tabela, miejsce, wartosc )`

And your insert value have to be quoted
wpis_email = """ 'whatever' """

First try without the `try/except`, as this eats any error messages

Comment: without the try/except working because treats variable wpis_email as column not as value

Comment: OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'mail@mail.com' in 'field list'") when value wpis_email = "mail@mail.com"

Comment: This adds three NULL in db

Comment: I changed it to sql = "INSERT INTO '%s' ('%s') VALUES ('%s')" % tabela, miejsce, (wartosc) and error is:
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: I use: "sql = "INSERT INTO '%s' ('%s') VALUES ('%s')" % (tabela, miejsce, wartosc)" and i have error: "ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''mail' ('email') VALUES ('nom')' at line 1")" I see variables is ok because is syntax error

Comment: table and column names don't need quotes, values do

And see example above `( tabela, miejsce, wartosc )`