# Python variables in MySQL: INSERT INTO %s

Tags: python, mysql

This question has been asked bevor ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122768/python-variables-in-mysql)), but no answer is working for me and unfortunally I am not allowed to add a comment, because I'm new here.
I didn't know what else to do than asking the question again, sorry for this - please tell me the right way to do.

I want to insert Python variables into a MySQL table named by a Python variable.
I figured out, to create the table by:

```
curs.execute ("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s LIKE table""" %(today))
```

I also figured out to insert values like this:

```
curs.execute (
        """ INSERT INTO table (column)
            VALUES (%s) """,
            (variable))
```

Now I tried

```
today = "table_name"
variable = "name"
curs.execute (
        """ INSERT INTO %s (column)
            VALUES (%s) """,
            ( table, variable ))
```

I'll get this error:

(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''table_name' (column …' at line 1")

I also tried:

```
today = "table_name"
variable = "name"
curs.execute (
            """ INSERT INTO %s (column)
                VALUES (%s) """
                % ( table, variable ))
```

I'll get this error:

(1054, "Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'")

I guess there's something wrong with the strings …

Thank you for answers!

Comment: you need to specify your column as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the `%s` with `?` and let sqlite handle the insertion. (Also helps preventing SQL injection attacks in web applications)

```
table_name = "today"
variable = "name"
curs.execute ("INSERT INTO ? (column) VALUES (?)",(table_name, variable))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
today = "table_name"
variable = "name"
curs.execute (
        """ INSERT INTO :table_name (column)
            VALUES (:variable_name) """,
            {'table_name': today, 'variable_name': variable})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have muddled your variables in your third, not working code snippet. instead try:

```
table_name = "today"
variable = "name"
curs.execute (
    """ INSERT INTO %s (column)
        VALUES (%s) """,
        ( table_name, variable ))
```

This will create a table named 'Today' with one column named 'column' with one data value in it 'name'. 
For this to work you will need to have previously created a table that has this column available. 
So your create code needs to change:

```
"""create table "today" ("column" varchar2(16BYTE), *add extra columns here if you wish*)"""
```

Comment: just edit your previous answer instead of posting two answers.